# Did the original airing of Warehouse 13's pilot include the song "Disturbia"?

Tags: soundtrack, warehouse-13

I saw the pilot episode of *[Warehouse 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warehouse_13)* when it originally aired on Syfy in 2009. There is a scene where Myka is driving in her car to Warehouse 13 for the first time. She is on a paved road and drives past a dirt road intersection. Myka then backs her car up, realizing that she missed her turn to the Warehouse, and goes down that dirt road. She is a bit miffed that the Warehouse is in such a remote location.

When I rewatched the episode recently on DVD, there was an instrumental soundtrack playing during this scene. But in my memory of the pilot, Rhianna's "[Disturbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_%28song%29)" song was playing. Specifically, these lyrics:

> Throw on your brake lights
>   We're in the city of wonder
>   Ain't gonna play nice
>   Watch out, you might just go under
>   Better think twice
>   Your train of thought will be altered
>   So if you must falter be wise

The reason I remember this was because I thought it clever that the lyric "We're in the city of wonder" was connecting with Mrs. Fredrick's "invitation to endless wonder" (which Myka said was creepy). I also remember hearing the catchy "bum-bum-be-dum" part of the song being played.

I know that TV shows sometimes have to replace soundtracks for home release due to licensing issues (*WKRP in Cincinnati* notably [ran into this with its DVD release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKRP_in_Cincinnati#Music_licensing)), so it's not out of the realm of possibility that *Warehouse 13* changed the music during this scene.

Did the original airing of *Warehouse 13*'s pilot include the song "Disturbia"? Or did I just make up this memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## YES!

Apparently *some of* your memory is fine.

Mrs Fredericks refers to "endless wonder" when speaking to **Pete** who thinks it's creepy.

[This site](https://www.tunefind.com/show/warehouse-13/season-1/6213) confirms that *Disturbia* did, in fact, feature on some version of the show.

[image]

I've...ahem...checked with an *acquired* version of the *broadcast version* and it does indeed play with **Pete**'s approach to the Warehouse.

Comment: Funny that I remembered a background detail like the soundtrack, but misremembered the character who was in the scene! I guess since it was early in the first episode, and they weren't doing anything distinctive of their characters, I swapped them. Thanks for tracking this down and *acquiring* the broadcast version to confirm!